Shiro filter not working in Spring Boot application
Springboot3 + Shiro1.5.3
I have configured a Shiro filter (with JWT) in my Spring Boot application, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. I've followed the setup instructions and added the necessary configurations, but the filter is not intercepting requests as it should. Here is my configuration
// ShiroConfig.java

@Configuration
public class ShiroConfig {

    // Other configurations...
    @Bean("lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
    public LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
    }


    @Bean("securityManager")
    public SecurityManager securityManager(UserRealm realm) {
        DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
        securityManager.setRealm(realm);
        return securityManager;
    }

    @Bean("shiroFilter")
    public ShiroFilterFactoryBean getShiroFilterFactoryBean(@Qualifier("securityManager") SecurityManager securityManager) {
        ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
        shiroFilter.setSecurityManager(securityManager);

        Map<String, Filter> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("jwt", new UserFilter());
        shiroFilter.setFilters(map);

        Map<String, String> filterMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        filterMap.put("/**", "jwt");
        shiroFilter.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterMap);
        return shiroFilter;
    }
}

and my filter is as follows:
@Slf4j
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class UserFilter extends BasicHttpAuthenticationFilter {

    @Override
    protected boolean executeLogin(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServiceException {
        //...
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isAccessAllowed(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, Object mappedValue) {
        try {
            executeLogin(request, response);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

Despite setting up the filter and defining the filter chain in my Shiro configuration, the filter doesn't seem to be intercepting requests.
After my debugging, I found that the request doesn't even need to go through the isAccessAllowed() method of the filter.

For starters why is there an @Component and @Scope that doesn't really make sense as you should use 1 instance. Next to that there is a Spring Boot Starter for apache Shiro shouldn't you be using that instead of manual configuration?

@M.Deinum
I've tried removing these two annotations and found that it still doesn't work. Additionally, since I'm integrating JWT with Shiro, I need to manually configure a lot of things. I feel like my configuration itself shouldn't have any issues, but the filter just won't run.

I have resolved this issue.
It was caused by the simultaneous use of javax and jakarta in the project.
